# How do I isolate a hardware malfunction in a PC build?

Tags: windows

I am trying to revive an old build to use as a spare. I installed a clean windows 10 on a WD 1TB HDD using my main computer. I plugged it into the problem machine and it worked perfectly. I went about installing all my software and such and about an hour or two in I get a black screen (no cursor, no CPU activity). Upon restarting I get the boot menu, and windows logo, but before anything else, I get the same black screen and no activity on CPU light

I thought it might be the HDD, So I repeated the process with a second drive with the same result. So, I took the hard drive and plugged it back into the good PC and it worked fine.

It must be a hardware issue, no? What could cause that? Motherboard? CPU?

I can obtain a parts list if the specifics would be helpful.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: "black screen and no activity on CPU light" is there **any** activity? (i.e. fans; PSU appears to be on; LED lit on the mainboard etc.) First thought is thermal shutdown or PSU failure, but probably not if the system is still "ON on."

Comment: Yes, fans are going, leds on, etc. The monitor is receiving signal, though screen is black.

Comment: "I went about installing all my software..." How do you know it's not *software* incompatible with the machine? Try running another OS from USB drive, e.g. Ubuntu Live. If that works without issues, it's *not hardware* at fault (you already replaced the HDD, so that's not at fault).

Comment: I have a drive with mint on it, I will try that. It's just not in correlation with any specific install- that is, it didn't happen directly after I installed something.